# Get int position from string PHP

Tags: php

I receive data from a PUSH service. This data is compressed with gzcompress(). At the very Beginning of the data, it contains an int which is the length of the data contained. This is done after the gzcompress(); So a sample data would be:

```
187xœËHÍÉÉ,
```

Which is produced by

```
echo '187'.gzcompress('Hello');
```

Now, I don't know the length of the int, it could be 1 digit it could be 10 digits. I also don't know the first character to find the position of the beginning of a string.

Any ideas on how to retrieve/subtract the int?

```
$length_value=???
$string_value=???
```

Comment: You could just cast it to int `echo (int)"187xœËHÍÉÉ,";` or maybe use a regex `^\d+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the compressed data would **NEVER** start with a digit, then a regex would be easiest:

```
$string = '187xœËHÍÉÉ,';
preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$number = $matches[0];
$compressed_data = substr($string, 0, strlen($number));
```

If the compressed data DOES start with a digit, then you're going to end up with corrupt data - you'll have absolutely no way of differentiating where the 'length' value stops and the compressed data starts, e.g.

```
$compressed = '123foo';
$length = '6';

$your_string = '6123foo';
```

Ok - is that a string of length 61, with compressed data 23foo? or 612 + 3foo?

Comment: It's impossible to get the number unless there is a delimiter between the number and the data

Comment: Not sure what you mean here `Assuming that the compressed data would NEVER start with a digit` while using `^(\d+)`. Note that `^` implies that the digits are at the beginning.

Comment: @MarcB ah I finally got what you meant +1

Comment: if you're in control of this service, then don't embed the length data like that in the response. either just send the data and let the client count the length, or use proper data/metadata separation techniques, like putting the length as a content-length header.

Comment: At very least, add some sort of delimiter

Comment: @StephenTG: also somewhat insecure. no guarantee that the compressed data won't accidentally start with that delimiter either. could build a dynamic delimeter after the start of the gz data's been analyzed, but it's easier to just use a content-length header and completely eliminate the problem.

Comment: $compressed_data is the number value as well. It should be substr($string,strlen($number),strlen($string))

Comment: @MarcB Fair enough. I just figured that if you had a "|" or something after the length, a regex to capture all digits up to the first "|" ought to work regardless of the compressed data. Wasn't really thinking about security.

Comment: quick workaround would be to START the string with that dynamic delimiter, so the client can figure out what it is, , e.g. `|||6|||123foo`. start of string -> digits = delimiter, then digits -> delimiter = length, then delimiter->end of string = data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match()` to catch the integer at the start of the string.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Well without an actual pattern this answer is useless, don't you agree ?

Comment: Not really he asked for a way, I gave him him some guidance. Sure I could have put the regex in though. Perhaps it should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$contents = "187xœËHÍÉÉ,";
$length = (int)$contents;
$startingPosition = strlen((string)$length);
$original = gzuncompress(substr($contents, $startingPosition), $length);
```

But I feel this may fail if the first compressed byte is a number.